# Is wrapping log4net to reduce coupling an antipattern?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, log4net

Is wrapping log4net to reduce coupling an antipattern? Or injecting the logger instance into a public property an antipattern? How do you approach the log4net dependency?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a transversal layer?

Comment: by transversal i meant that this layer will be available for all the other layers, like a security layer

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a logger for below reasons -

1. It isolates the change only to logger, in future if you want to change it to something better no cascaded changes.
2. It makes your life easy when you want to write the test cases. You can easily mock the stuff required.
3. If due to certain reasons you need to have more than one logger in your app, then wrapper helps. You can change the logger through some factory / registry. Ex - if a code is shared among different platforms/environments where you want to have different logger. You can make it factory/registry driven.

So, my view is good to wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

The [service locator](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) is [considered](http://twitter.com/#!/jeremydmiller/status/80657730188214272) an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) by many on the leading edge of the .NET community. I would say that logging is usually a very benign feature of our applications. It's essentially "write-only". We are never making decisions based on queries of the logging system.

log4net is also a system that's easy to turn off, doesn't throw exceptions, silently fails, can update its configuration on the fly... there's almost no reason to swap out implementations once its in.

So, I say that, in application code, it's ok to use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

We define a logging interface, and have a log4net implementation, a unitTest implementation and a null implementation.

We use dependency injection to pass a loggingInterface implementation around.

The unit test implementation has additional methods, like 'bool ErrorWasLogged()', so that in our unit tests we can assert that important information is logged. For tests where we are not interested in testing what was logged, we use the null implementation.